# problem in using selenium-maven-plugin

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I'm using selenium-maven-plugin.
http://mojo.codehaus.org/selenium-maven-plugin/
I have tried at headless linux with xvfb goal.
Below execution progress...

1. xvfb
2. start-server (Selenium RC server)
3. run unit test
4. stop-server

But, at 3, not working...

```
16:34:50,532 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer] Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 14.3-b01
16:34:50,532 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer] OS: Linux 2.6.18-128.el5xen i386
16:34:50,541 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer] v2.0 [a2], with Core v2.0 [a2]
...
16:34:50,636 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer] Version Jetty/5.1.x
16:34:50,637 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
16:34:50,637 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
16:34:50,638 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/,/]
16:34:50,659 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@1462851
16:34:50,659 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
16:34:50,663 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener] Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
16:34:50,664 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@122cdb6
16:34:51,279 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Credential] Checking Resource aliases
Selenium Server started
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default}]
...

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
...
16:34:53,023 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Credential] Checking Resource aliases
16:34:53,027 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler] Command request: setSpeed[500, ] on session null
16:34:53,031 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler] Got result: OK on session null
...
16:34:53,040 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory] creating new remote session
...
16:34:53,154 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher] Preparing Firefox profile...
16:35:02,393 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher] Launching Firefox...
```

No more than, not progress...
Anybody knows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on logging and set a timeout, then check the log for errors.
The problem may be caused by selenium not being able to find or open firefox.